# How to implement near-real time autocompletion using lucene?

Tags: autocomplete, lucene

Lucene offers different Autocompletion options:

[org.apache.lucene.search.suggest.Lookup](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_0_0/suggest/org/apache/lucene/search/suggest/Lookup.html)

I was using the [AnalyzingSuggester](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_0_0/suggest/org/apache/lucene/search/suggest/analyzing/AnalyzingSuggester.html) which is good but it does not support changing data, i.e. when the index changes one needs to reindex everything.

Therefore I tries out the [AnalyzingInfixSuggester](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_0_0/suggest/org/apache/lucene/search/suggest/analyzing/AnalyzingInfixSuggester.html). This has and [add method](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_0_0/suggest/org/apache/lucene/search/suggest/analyzing/AnalyzingInfixSuggester.html#add-org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef-java.util.Set-long-org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef-) and an [update method](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_0_0/suggest/org/apache/lucene/search/suggest/analyzing/AnalyzingInfixSuggester.html#update-org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef-java.util.Set-long-org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef-) but no remove.

Does someone know if it is possible to implement near-real time suggestions with pure lucene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know why this is not part of the public implementation. At the end I extended the AnalyzingInfixSuggester like this:

```
public class MyAnalyzingInfixSuggester extends AnalyzingInfixSuggester {

    public MyAnalyzingInfixSuggester(Directory dir, Analyzer analyzer) throws IOException {
        super(dir, analyzer);
    }

    public void remove(String text) throws IOException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        // call method ensureOpen via reflection since it is private
        Method method = AnalyzingInfixSuggester.class.getDeclaredMethod("ensureOpen");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(this);
        Query query1 = new TermQuery(new Term(TEXT_FIELD_NAME, text.toLowerCase()));

        BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery.Builder()
                .add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
                .build();
        writer.deleteDocuments(booleanQuery);
    }
}
```

Comment: As an alternative to using a boolean query to select the document(s) to be deleted, you can use a term to select a document:  `writer.deleteDocuments(new Term("exacttext", text));`. This uses [`exacttext`](https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/5f2a4998a079278ada89ce7bfa3992673a91c5c9/lucene/suggest/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/suggest/analyzing/AnalyzingInfixSuggester.java#L109) for an exact lookup (useful for deleting a single document). I also needed to call `suggester.refresh();` after calling `suggester.remove("some text");`.